# Concatenate two int arrays

Tags: c, int, concatenation

This might be simple, but I can't seem to make it work.

I have:

```
int string1[100];
int string2[100];
```

both containing '1' and '0' values (binary) and I want to concatenate them.

How do I combine those two integers to get a single one?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want another array with the 200 elements?

Comment: Do you know the difference between strings and integer arrays?

Comment: Why allocate 64000 bits when you only intend to store 200 bits?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use either a loop, or `memcpy()`.

It's unclear if both arrays are 100% full, i.e. if all elements are used. If they are, just do:

```
int string3[200];

memcpy(string3, string1, sizeof string1);
memcpy(string3 + sizeof string1 / sizeof string1, string2, sizeof string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a loop. Something like :

```
int concatenated[200],i,j;
for(i=0,j=0;j<100;j++)
{
concatenated[i]=string1[j];
i++;
}

for(j=0;j<100;j++)
{
concatenated[i]=string2[j];
i++
}
```

BTW do you really want to use integer arrays? Can you use strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0,j=0;
//first find where string1 ends, where the '\0' character is. 
//then add string 2 from that point until we reach the '\0' of string 2.
while(string1[i] != '\0')
i++; 
while((string1[i++] = string2[j++]) != '\0');
```

this adds string 2 to string 1, reverse the strings matrices if you want it the other way round.I am not sure if you want a new array, or to join string2 to string1. i Assumed you are joining them together, if your arrays are full already start out with string1[200]; you won't need a new array then.

**EDIT** since you wanted a new array.

```
 int new_array[200] = {0};
 int i=j=k =0;
 while((new_array[i++] = string1[i++]) != '\0');
 i--;
 while((new_array[i++] = string2[k++] ) != '\0');
```

Comment: I want to get a new array with the two strings. Also, they aren't full; they contain some binary digits and null characters

Comment: of course you could use the memcpy function aswell, but i edited my post if you want just some raw code